# Set nav position to top on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on some CSS to set my nav to position top on scroll. My nav markup is:

```
<nav class="flex-nav" id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>...
```

The current position of my nav is:

```
.flex-nav ul{
 position: fixed;
 top: 6em;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

I want this to be set to top when I scroll down, and unstick when I scroll to the top of page again and set it back to top:6em.

Will I need JavaScript to handle this, and also set a id on the nav to use it in the JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

```
onload = _ => {
    let nav = document.getElementById("nav");
    let basePos = nav.offsetTop;
    setInterval(_ => {
        nav.style.top = Math.max(0, basePos - scrollY) + "px";
    }, 20);
};
```

This runs every 20 milliseconds (approximately) and updates the elements position.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working snippet written in pure Javascript:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
  if (body.scrollTop > 0) {
    nav.className += " no-indent"
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("no-indent");
  }
}, true)
```

```css
.flex-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.no-indent {
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="flex-nav" id="nav">
</nav>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :) I guess that .no-ident sets the position to top:0 when scroll is larger then 0, else doesn't use it. But I don't see .no-ident in the markup? So, thats not necessary then?

Comment: @user2371684, yes, you're right. This class is not in HTML code, because it's applying via Javascript in this row: `document.getElementById('nav').className += " no-indent"`. And it's applying and removing based on scrolled pixels from top: "if scrollTop > 0" - add class, "if scrollTop === 0" - remove class

Comment: MDN says "Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications." You should at least save the element in a variable.